# How can I do 2 Domains in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain

I have a webserver configurated with the domain yyan.ch then I have a directory named frace65. in this directory is a Wordpress installation with the domain frace65.com How can I reach the wordpress over frace65.com and yyan.ch/frace65

Comment: Your domain name "/" directory name

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a virtual host for sub domain site. The Document root will be same only Server Name will change.

Just Follow this Link https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network